# How can I remove an accept-encoding request header in nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-headers, gzip, nginx-reverse-proxy

The recent update to zlib due to [a security hole](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-25032) appears to cause a major problem when serving PHP-FPM 8.0 via nginx on Ubuntu focal. Any requests with a gzip encoding fail right at the start of the response, though nginx logs the requests as successful and the correct size. If I make requests without an `Accept-Encoding` header, it works perfectly. As a workaround, I'm trying to disable all gzip support, but it seems to be remarkably persistent... So far I have tried these settings in nginx:

```
gzip off;
fastcgi_buffering off;
add_header Accept-Encoding "";
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
```

and I've also checked that there are no other directives that turn these back on again by grepping `nginx -T` output.

However, if I dump the request headers from PHP (i.e. after it's been through nginx), I still see this accept header:

```
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br, zstd
```

so nginx is *not* stripping it from the request before it's passed through to PHP-FPM. I've tried setting these directives at the server and location levels, with the same results.

In PHP I've disabled all output buffering, but it doesn't appear to be possible to disable zlib without a recompile.

How can I get nginx to strip this request header so that neither nginx nor PHP will compress responses?

Answer (score 0):

`proxy_set_header` directive is for **proxying** requests, i.e. for passing them through *HTTP-to-HTTP*-server chain. And you have the *FastCGI* server next in chain, so your set of directives starts from `fastcgi_`.

You can completely disable passing request headers to the PHP by setting `fastcgi_pass_request_headers` to off, or you can drop the specific header by resetting it with `fastcgi_set_header`.

Comment: I'm running the nginx-extra package with all bells and whistles, but nginx tells me that the `fastcgi_set_header` directive doesn't exist.